# Do Shimano RS100 wheels have two ratchets inside the freehub?

Tags: maintenance, freehub

Can anybody confirm Shimano RS100 wheel rear hubs have two ratchets inside the freehubs? It looks like there are sockets for 3 ratchets but there are only 2 ratchets. Since we bought the bike second hand, we don't know whether it has been serviced before.

What is the difference between having two or more ratchets in a freehub?

Comment: Is it a “standard” Shimano screw-on freehub module? It’s rare for anyone to open those up for servicing so it might be a manufacturing cost move to only use 2 of 3 available pawls.

Comment: @WarrenBurton You can see the rear hub model here: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tiagra-4700/FH-RS400.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, seeing only 2 of the 3 slots occupied is normal and what you'll typically see when you open one. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

When there are 3 sockets its is likely they all need to be there. Those tiny bits of metal are all that keeps your weight when standing on the pedals. It is better to divert that load over multiple parts, as the load per part gets smaller.

Comment: Not so! One ratchet is carrying all of your load. These aren't components that would do load sharing. Minuscule differences in the clearances makes it impossible for load to be shared. This is similar to lockpicking, if you pick a lock, then there's only one pin that's binding and this is how single-pin picking works.